# Netty UDP Session Management

Tags: java, udp, netty

I am having some problems setting up a session management system for UDP with the Netty framework. I am confused about what is new per UDP remote client. For every new UDP remote client, does that client get a new ChannelPipelineFactory, or is a new Channel created per new remote client?

I have 2 ports, port 161 and port 162 that are both UDP ports and both will be receiving data from numerous UDP clients. How can I differentiate between the clients? I started to create a session management service based on `RemoteAddress` provided by `DatagramPacket.sender()` but I don't know if it's safe to attach to the `ChannelHandlerContext` attribute() chain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since UDP is connection less, the `DatagramPacket.sender` will be your only option to route messages to the appropriate session. There is conceptually only one `ChannelPipelineFactory` and in fact only one `Channel` for UDP for the application. As far as I know it is not safe to attach the `ChannelHandlerContext`. The way to deal with multiple clients is to use a `Map` with the key as the `DatagramPacket.sender` address and value as your `session`.

Comment: Thank you, I thought that was the only way to go about it but wasn't entirely sure.